# No database connection vagrant vm nginx

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, vagrant

I have a vagrant virtual machine running using virtual box on windows 8. Everything was working fine until I changed from an apache2 vm to nginx. Now, I just cannnot connect to my database. If I connect using the command line (putty to be specific) I can connect create, delete database etc. no problem. If I use the same credentials in my script I get the error message: Database connection could not be established.

My connection credentials:

```
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'login');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
```

I just cannot figure out what might be the problem! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't DB_HOST be the IP of your vagrant box?

Comment: this cannot be, 127.0.0.1 is localhost. if you call your box from the outside, it would have some other (internal) IP.